# Setting map language to English in Openstreetmap with LeafletJS

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I'm using LeafletJS to add a map component to my app. Everything is fine and dandy except for the localization of the map. Some country names are shown in the local language (I'm assuming).

Is there a way to show the country names in English?

[image]

This is the current code that I use

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution : '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                noWrap      : true 
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: see [this related question](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/6188/mapping-layer-africa-in-english) on help.osm.org.

Comment: Thanks tyr, will check it out

Comment: All you need is a right tile server, you can choose one from : -
http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Comment: https://www.osmap.us/ appears to use `'https://osmap.{s}.tile.mapcdn.net/en/map/v1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The standard tile server of OSM tries to display labels in the local language whenever such data is available (local meaning the language of the country currently displayed, not *your* local language). The [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), served by the tile server, already contain the labels, so you cannot remove them afterwards. But you can:

- [render them on your own](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) (which requires suitable hardware) with an adjusted [stylesheet](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stylesheet), or
- use tiles without labels and create a label overlay
- try to see if there is a different [tile server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_servers) which only displays english labels. [open mapquest](http://open.mapquest.com/) for example has tiles based on OSM data where all labels are in english.
- [Map internationalization](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization) in the OSM wiki has some more examples

And always remember to comply with the tile usage policy of the tile server you choose.

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out. I'm using the tile server for a prototype app, and will be switching to a different paid server or most likely roll our own soon.

Comment: I went with open mapquest. For anyone with the same question, here's a handy list of tile servers you can use - https://gist.github.com/mourner/1804938

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the corresponding project is dead. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is to work with basemaps instead of openstreetmap

```
const mainLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  minZoom: 3,
  maxZoom: 17,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://carto.com/">carto.com</a> contributors'
});
mainLayer.addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: This example does not work when zooming in. It reverts to local.

Comment: This tile worked for me. Even when I zoom in or zoom out. But I am not sure if it is free or limited. I cannot find the information about the free tier on its website. Do you know whether there are any limited requests per month?

Answer (score 6):

For **German** language

You can use this german tile server: `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  ...
})
...
```

Comment: in case someone would like to do the same, but for French: 

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 100,
      minZoom: 1,
      attribution : '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      noWrap      : true
    });

Also a good link to check for tiles url: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

Answer (score 0):

you can check [leaflet providers](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/), there are a lot of working solutions.
For example, for EN language:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
 {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
subdomains: 'abcd',
maxZoom: 20
}
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).